# ASP.NET Register Control CreatedUser Event (Acting like it worked but no users are in my database)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to create a custom profile object after the registration of a new user.  The problem I'm having is that the user registration control does not seem to be storing to my database.  When I do the following:

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

        MembershipUser newUser = Membership.GetUser(RegisterUser.UserName);
    }
```

I can see that newUser has all the properties given in the RegisterUser control plus the additional imortant ones such as ProviderUserKey (implying it was legitimately created).  Where is it getting the user from if it is not in the database?  When I query the table to select the top 1000 it's completely empty.

Comment: out of curiosity..what does the .webconfig look like..? can you show that as well for the section that has `cookieless=` also make sure you have `<authentication mode="Forms">` set in the .config file.. did you debug the code as well.

Comment: Authentication mode was already set to forms.  I don't see cookieless in the web.config, and yes I have tried to debug.  No unusual errors until I try saving my custom object with the properties from the returned MembershipUser - which fails because it cannot find the user in the aspnet_Users table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a fluke with App_Data.  Instead of being hooked up to our database it was making it's own database in the App_Data folder.

What happens is when the project is set up, if there is no connection string specified, .NET creates it's own connection string "ApplicationServices".  Even after entering your own connection string it's necessary to change your new connection's name anywhere "ApplicationServices" was used.